# Find conditional probabiltity

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

Question

1. at least $3 = 1-p(y=3) =7/10 
   or p(y=3)+p(y=4)= 5/10 which one is correct?

i'm still confused about the " at least " term.

2. conditional

positive eranings = 2/10 + 3/10 + 2/10 = 7/10

(at least $3  ∩ positive earnings) = 3/10 + 2/10 = 5/10

therefore

P(at least $3 | positive earnings) =

(5/10) / (7/10) = 0.7143

correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, **at least** 3 dollars indicates that $Y≥3$; in this case he earns 3 or 4 dollars. The probabilities for $Pr\left( Y\geq 3 \right)=Pr\left( Y=3 \right)+Pr\left( Y=4 \right)=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

Positive earnings, as you said, are $Y>0$, so $Pr\left( Y>0 \right)=\frac{7}{10}$

---

For the conditional probability, it's asking you for $Pr\left( Y\geq 3|Y>0 \right)$

Do this: $$Pr\left( Y\geq 3|Y>0 \right)=\frac{Pr\left( Y\geq 3\cap Y>0 \right)}{Pr\left( Y>0 \right)}=\frac{Pr\left( Y\geq 3 \right)}{Pr\left( Y>0 \right)}$$

Comment: thanks i guess the final answer is the same with me.

Comment: yeh the same answer